# Convert a javascript string into a 2-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this data coming from a REST method using jquery's getJSON method.

```
"[Date.UTC(2010,0,0,0,0,0,0), 157],[Date.UTC(2010,0,0,0,0,420,1), 157],[Date.UTC(2010,0,0,0,0,420,2), 282],[Date.UTC(2010,0,0,0,0,600,3), 282],[Date.UTC(2010,0,0,0,0,600,4), 125],[Date.UTC(2010,0,0,0,0,900,5), 125],[Date.UTC(2010,0,0,0,0,900,6), 282],[Date.UTC(2010,0,0,0,0,2100,7), 282],[Date.UTC(2010,0,0,0,0,2100,8), 125],[Date.UTC(2010,0,0,0,0,2400,9), 125],[Date.UTC(2010,0,0,0,0,2400,10), 295],[Date.UTC(2010,0,0,0,0,3600,11), 295],[Date.UTC(2010,0,0,0,0,3600,12), 125],[Date.UTC(2010,0,0,0,0,3900,13), 125],[Date.UTC(2010,0,0,0,0,3900,14), 288],[Date.UTC(2010,0,0,0,0,5100,15), 288],[Date.UTC(2010,0,0,0,0,5100,16), 125],[Date.UTC(2010,0,0,0,0,5400,17), 125]"
```

It comes back as a string.  I need to parse it into a two dimensional array.  Each item in the array should have a date and a value.

I also have full control over the REST method, so I could change the way the data returns.  I'm interested in making this as fast as possible.

Here's what we are doing now which I think could be improved:

```
 var jqxhr = $.getJSON(getDataURL, function(dataResult) {
        var result = dataResult;

        result =result.replace(/\]\,\[/g, ']:[');
        result = result.replace(/\)\,/g, ');');

        var tempArray = result.split(':');

        var myarray = new Array();
        myarray[0] = new Array(2); // Make the first element an array of two elements
        for(i = 0; i < tempArray.length; i ++)
        {
          myarray[i] = tempArray[i].split(';');
          myarray[i][1] = myarray[i][1].replace(/\"/g,'');
          myarray[i][1] = myarray[i][1].replace(/\]/g,'');  
          myarray[i][0] = myarray[i][0].replace(/\[/g,'');                             
        }                                                               
    })
```

Comment: as horrible as it sounds, I'd put brackets at the start and end of the string and use eval

Comment: @Joseph I thought about using jQuery.parseJSON but I don't think my string is valid for that function.  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/  I'll try sending back the data so it's valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As much as I'm going to get flack for this (`eval` tends to be a security risk), I would just do

```
var myarray = eval("[" + result + "]");
```

Comment: I was going to post the same answer. In this case, `eval` works (you don't even need to add the enclosing brackets). But one should know what he is doing before using `eval`. Could start by reading this SO thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil

Comment: @bfavaretto Wow! thanks for the link! I will be sure to read it when I get home.  Also, I tried it without the brackets and it only assigned it the last array in the string so I think the brackets are necessary.  Again, thank you for the link!

Comment: You're right about the brackets, sorry! I tested with only part of the original string...

Comment: *eval* is not, of itself, a secuirity risk. Running code from unknown sources without checking might be, but you don't need *eval* for that.

Answer (score 0):

You should use JSON to return data from your server to your JS script. That will be pretty easier to manipulate it as an array.